# Likelihood ratio test computation help

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, estimation

I am trying to solve an problem from Rice's Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis (Problem 9.41) and I got stuck doing some computation. Namely, let $X_i\sim\text{Bin}(n_i,p_i)$ for $i = 1,\dots,m$. I am supposed to devise a log-likelihood ratio test for the null hypothesis $H_0: p_1 =\cdots=p_m$, alternative being that not all are equal, and also to find its large sample distribution. I have computed the likelihood ratio to be

$$
\Lambda = \frac{\prod_{i = 1}^m \hat p_i^{x_i}(1-\hat p_i)^{n_i-x_i}}{\hat p^{\sum_{i=1}^mx_i}(1-\hat p)^{\sum_{i=1}^m n_i-x_i}},
$$
where $\hat p_i = x_i/n_i$ and $$\hat p= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^m n_i}. $$
However, when I try to compute $2\text{log} \Lambda $, I do not get anything remotely useful. I know that the large sample distribution is supposed to be $\chi^2(m-1)$, but I do not have any idea how to arrive at that conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Thank you for showing us what you have done so far. Since this is a question from a textbook, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

I think you inversed the numerator with the denominator. If we want to test :$$H_0:\theta\in\Theta_0 \space vs\space H_1:\theta\in\Theta_0^c$$
where $\Theta$ is the parametric space, then:
 $$\Lambda(x)=\frac{\sup_{\Theta_0}L(\theta|x)}{\sup_{\Theta}L(\theta|x)}$$
 Assuming that, $\Lambda$ should be written like this:
$$\Lambda = \frac{\hat p^{\sum_{i=1}^mx_i}(1-\hat p)^{\sum_{i=1}^m n_i-x_i}}{\prod_{i = 1}^m \hat p_i^{x_i}(1-\hat p_i)^{n_i-x_i}}.
$$

Comment: That is true. However, in your case, the log likelihood is defined as $\lambda = -2\log\Lambda$ and the minus in front of the logarithm inverts the fraction. So I my case, where I want to compute the log likelihood, I think it does not matter. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @letreetlneant my bad, I didn't pay attention to  $ 2 \log \Lambda$.

Comment: @letreetlneant what about the exact distribution, do you know what it is?